# How to check if one of the strings from an array are in the URL/window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array:

```
var checkURL = ['abc123', 'abc124', 'abc125'];
```

How can I check if one of the strings in the array exists in the window.location.pathname?

I know individually I can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("abc123") > -1) {
           alert("your url contains the string abc123");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a for-loop for a linear search.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var checkURL = ['abc123', 'abc124', 'abc125'];

    for (var i = 0; i < checkURL.length; i++) {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf(checkURL[i]) > -1) {
            alert("your url contains the string "+checkURL[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option that uses `join` and a regular expression.

```
var checkURL = ['abc123', 'abc124', 'abc125'];
var url = window.location.href;

var Matches = RegExp(checkURL.join('|')).exec(url);

if (Matches) {
    alert('your url contains the string ' + Matches[0]);
}
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArEZV/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkURL.length; i++) {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf(checkURL[i]) > -1) {
           alert("your url contains the string " + checkURL[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the test data into a map

```
var checkURL = {'abc123':'', 'abc124':'', 'abc125':''};
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');

for(var i=0;i<url.length;i++){
var targetUrl=url[i];
if(typeof checkURL[targetUrl]!=='undefined'){
alert(targetUrl);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And for the reference this elegant solution:

```
var checkURL = ['abc123', 'abc124', 'abc125'];

var inArray = checkURL.some(function(el) {
    return ~location.href.indexOf(el);
}); // true/false
```

*Note: this requires shim for the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method!*

Answer (score 0):

A loop can do this:

```
for(var p in checkURL){
   if(window.location.pathname.indexOf(checkURL[p]) > -1){
      alert("your url contains the string");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged jquery in your question, use each() function

```
jQuery.each(checkURL, function(i,v) {
if(window.location.href.indexOf(checkURL[i]) > -1) {
           alert("your url contains the string " + checkURL[i]);
        }
});
```

No need to use i and v variables as the depict key value pair